# Not able to create a new SXA Accordian items in IE

Tags: sxa, sitecore-api

I am trying to add a new SXA Accordian component from Experience editor in IE but not able to get 'Create' link which is working fine in Chrome. PFB Screenshots

[image: Chrome]

[image: IE]

Comment: Click on data then click back on accordions. I've seen an issue where the create button does not appear until you switch between root items.

Comment: @MichaelWest, I tried switching between the root items but no luck

Comment: @ManideepYechuri I will check this for you tomorrow on my dev instance.

Comment: @ManideepYechuri I was not able to reproduce this issue. Ensure that you've correct Compatibility Mode settings in the IE (use the latest compatibility mode available).